# How to construct a matrix $4×4$ with two parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been searching for a method to construct a $4×4$, $5×5$ or $6×6$ matrix $A$ with two parameters $α$ and $β$ satisfying this property:

> 1. If $α = β = 0$, then $A$ has no eigenvalue equal to $0$.
>
>    If at least one of $α$ and $β$ equal to one, then $A$ has an eigenvalue equal to $0$.

Is there any known method to construct such $A$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please remember that if no effort or context is provided, questions are prone to down votes.

Comment: I cuurently work to have one but its diffucult so i ask for method to try with

Comment: what about 4×4
diagonal matrix diag(1−a,1−b,1−a,1−b)